# Sequelize foreign key error on Heroku but not local testing

Tags: javascript, mysql, heroku, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I am new developer and am trying to teach myself Sequelize and mysql with some little test projects. What I have right now is a little RPG team strength analyzer. I have a SQL table of Units, which has schema (id, name, elementOne, elementTwo) - integer, string, string, string.

For now, the elementOne and ElementTwo tables are both the same 18 string values because I couldn't figure out how to set up the Sequelize query with foreign keys refs to the same table (e.g. just 'elements').

Adding to the Unit table works fine on a local server, but breaks on Heroku ONLY when trying to add a **third** unit with the following error:

```
Error was:  { SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: Cannot add or update a child  
row: a foreign key constraint fails (`heroku_f4daeab1e260595`.`units`, 
CONSTRAINT `units_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `elementtwos` (`id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Here are all the tables and the relationship declarations.

```
const Unit = sequelize.define('unit', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: false
  },
  image: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
    unique: false
  },
  elementOne: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: true,
    references: {
      model: Element,
      key: 'id'
    }
  },
  elementTwo: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: true,
    defaultValue: 10001,
    references: {
      model: ElementTwo,
      key: 'id'
    }
  }
});

const Element = sequelize.define('element', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: false
  }
});
const ElementTwo = sequelize.define('elementtwo', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: false
  }
});
```

After these are all loaded, I set up the following:

```
Unit.belongsTo(Element, {foreignKey: 'elementOne'});
Unit.belongsTo(ElementTwo, {foreignKey: 'elementTwo'});
ElementTwo.hasMany(Unit, {foreignKey: 'id'});
Element.hasMany(Unit, {foreignKey: 'id'});
```

And this is the query that Sequelize is doing (in a Unit.create({...}):

```
INSERT INTO `units` 
(`id`,`name`,`image`,`elementOne`,`elementTwo`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES 
 (DEFAULT,'raichu','http://longimgurl.png',13,10001,'2017-06-14 
12:57:54','2017-06-14 12:57:54');
```

If anyone can offer any advice it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is mysql error and because you define foreign key constraint on you table and try to insert unavailable value in fk field that does not exit in target table,

check `element` and `elementTwo` table and make sure this values are available